# Where to find log information in Azure portal

Tags: c#, azure, logging, telemetry

I have the following code about logging and the log data is stored in Azure somewhere. Probably in azure storage account. The following is the code:

```
private readonly TelemetryClient telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient();
private readonly ILogger logger;
logger = new TraceLogger(telemetryClient);
logger.LogError("Exception in TestService");
```

Now I tried searching for the "Exception In TestService" log in azure but I cannot find where it is. I have searched the storage account, blob containers and found nothing. Any suggestion on where I should find this information on azure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are using [Azure Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-insights-overview). If so, you can get the data collected by Application Insights on Azure portal. Refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/website-monitoring) for more details.

[image]